# What is the difference between 响，声，and 音

Tags: word-choice, difference

What is the difference between 响，声，and 音. When I check the English translation, it says

- 响: echo, sound, noise, make a sound, to sound, to ring, loud, classifier for noises
- 声: sound, voice, tone, noise, classifier for sounds
- 音: sound, noise, musical note, tone, news, syllable, reading (phonetic value of a character)

Pls help me clarify the difference, it is quite difficult to catch.

请帮我清楚分别“响”，“声”，和“音”。多谢你们。

Comment: I think you've pretty much already got it.

Comment: @user3306356 Pls help me distinguish with examples.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

响 - a type of sound. It is an adjective that can mean "loud ring" like 
响声音 = loud ringing noise

声 - depending on context, it can mean sound, noise, or voice. For example:
我把声音 = my voice
那是什么声音 = what is that sound/noise
Colloquially, you can shorten 声音 as 声, which would mean noise. You can also use the word 音 by itself to mean sound. But this is a bit atypical. Usually you would use both words together.

音 - as mentioned, when using this word by itself, it can mean sound. But it generally means "tone." So it's not noise or a loud sound.

音 can also be used with the word 樂. 
音樂 means music where 樂 is used to describe the type of sound (a happy sound)

Answer (score 0):

**Tuttle**

响〔響〕

> ADJECTIVE
>
> loud, noisy
>
> 教室里在考试, 你们说话声音别这么响。
>
> Jiàoshì li zài kǎoshì, nǐmen shuōhuà shēngyīn bié zhème xiǎng.
>
> There's an examination in progress in the classroom. Don't talk so loudly.

声

> NOUN
>
> sound, noise, voice
>
> 机器声太大, 我听不清你说什么。
>
> Jīqì shēng tài dà, wǒ tīng bu qīng nǐ shuō shénme.
>
> The noise from the machine is too loud; I can't hear what you're saying.

音

> NOUN
>
> sound

**Oxford**

> ① sound
>
> 噪音
>
> noise

Answer (score 0):

声音 sound，more like a word.Mostly,we use them together.There is no difference between 声 and 音.

响 make a sound loudly

声音很响。

The sound is loud.